# Configure angular parse app to work with mongo + heroku?

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, migration

How do I configure my angular web app to work with mongo + heroku?
When I try to perform a login I get this error.`cant authenticate to your mongo database`

Usually it's like this

```
Parse.initialize("xxxxxxx", "zzzzzzzz");
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your MongoDB is protected with password so inside your ParseServer NodeJS app you need to pass the username and password of your mongoDB in the following way:

'mongodb://{**username**}:{**password**}@{mongo_host}:{mongo_port}/{db_name}'

this should be located where you initialize the ParseServer

**Edit - how to initialize**

```
Parse.initialize("YOUR_APP_ID");
Parse.serverURL = 'http://localhost:1337/parse'
```

in the serverURL put your server URL where you deployed your parse server.

Comment: I have already done that, but I know on ios you change the `Parse.initialize()` to include the parse server link. Do I need to do that for my angular app?

Comment: ok, you need to use initialize and then pass the server URL where your app is deployed.. i edit the answer for you